# What is the best method to customize the display of author information on a node of a certain type?

Tags: 7, theming

Requirements: For nodes of a certain type (blog), I need to show the author information with the author image using a specific Image Style, the user name, the user profile description, and another custom user field.

The method I'm currently using is implementing theme_preprocess_node() to create a variable to pass to my node--blog.tpl.php file that includes the elements I need themed. This means I have calls to theme_image_style() in my theme_preprocess_node() function.

Is this the best method, or is there a "more Drupal" approach I'm missing?

If it helps, here is a snippet of code:

```
/**
 * Hook theme_preprocess_node
 */
function hotness_preprocess_node(&$vars) {  
  // for blog posts, style date and show intro image
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->type == 'blog') {
    // nice date
    $vars['date'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'F j, Y');

    // use image style for blog image
    $vars['blog_image'] = NULL;
    $blog_image = isset($node->field_blog_image['und'][0]) ? $node->field_blog_image['und'][0] : FALSE;
    if($blog_image) {
      $vars['blog_image'] = theme_image_style(array(
        'style_name' => 'introduction-image',
        'path' => $blog_image['uri'],
        'width' => $blog_image['width'],
        'height' => $blog_image['height'],
        'alt' => $blog_image['title'], // to make it easier to the end user I just show title
        'title' => $blog_image['title'],
         'attributes' => array('class' => 'blog-image')
      ));
    }

// I use user_load() because the node object doesn't have the user description.
$author = user_load($node->uid);

$author_image = '';
if(isset($author->picture->uri) && !empty($author->picture->uri)) {
  $author_image = theme_image_style(array(
    'style_name' => 'blog-author-image',
    'path' => $node->picture->uri,
    'width' => NULL,
    'height' => NULL,
    'alt' => t('User .') . $node->name,
    'title' => t('User ') . $node->name,
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('author-image')),
  ));
}

$author_name = l($node->name, 'user/' . $node->uid);
$author_desc = isset($author->field_description['und'][0]['safe_value']) ? 
  '<div class="author-description">' . $author->field_description['und'][0]['safe_value'] . '</div>': '';

// put it all together
$vars['author_block'] = $author_image . $author_name . $author_desc;
```

}
}

Comment: I can't seem to make the code display properly.

Comment: what theme do you use? Bartik shows the profile image with the blog post.

Comment: Omega. My previous comment refers to not being able to make the code display here, in the question ;)

Comment: A very minor adjustment for people who might use this code. When setting class attributes, you should use an array. 

So: `'attributes' => array('class' => array('author-image')),`.

This way you can easily add standard classes within your theme.

Answer (score 1):

In your code at

```
 $node->field_blog_image['und'][0]
```

this is still an array so you need to access the value of the field one more level deep in to that array you can access it as follows.

```
$node->field_blog_image['und'][0]['safe_value']
```

Rest of code looks good to me.